# The custom view added in the WKWebview is not listed during UITesting

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, wkwebview, xcuitest

I have a UITableview with the below view hierarchy.

```
UIViewController
  |--UITableView
     |--WKWebview
        |--ScrollView
           |--UIView
```

The `UIView` is added once the Webview load is completed and the view appeared properly in the UI.
When I run the UITestcases the dynamically added content is not listed during the `UITesting`.

The below approaches are tried and didn't work.

- Set `isAccessibilityElement` false to all the views in the mentioned hierarchy
- print the `app.debugDescription` the newly added view contents are not displayed
- print the `XCUIApplication()` and here also the newly added view contents are not displayed
- added the `accessibilityIdentifier` to all the views the newly added contents are not listed

Not sure whether this is expected behavior or am I doing something wrong here in adding the contents.

**Subview code:**

```
[tableViewCell.webView.scrollView addSubview:customView]
```

Help Appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed by adding the custom view to the accessibility elements list.

```
[self.view setAccessibilityElements:@[customView]];
```